# Android Pinterest SDK: PinIt button no longer functioning

Tags: android, pinterest, pin-it-sdk

We noticed the Pin It button is no longer working within our application. Pressing it doesn't result in anything occurring.

The PinItListener doesn't get any exception callbacks, but it returns false for whether it was pinned in onComplete.

Trying out the PinItDemo project bundled with the SDK, nothing occurs on click either. I tried it with our client ID and a new client ID I set up.

Since it stopped functioning between releases of our application, I'm assuming it's a Pinterest change. Did a Pinterest update break the PinItSDK? Is there something we can do to fix it?

Comment: Pinterest confirmed there are issues with the PinIt button and Pinterest 2.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in Pinterest for Android 2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if PinItSDK doesn't work anymore or what the problem is. But there is another way you can pin the content. You can use the base url to open Create Pin form like

```
http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?media=http://www.ournorthstar.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/test1.jpg&title=Sample&description=This+is+a+test+description
```

and pass it as an intent and start the activity.

Eg:

```
String shareUrl = "http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?media=http://www.ournorthstar.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/test1.jpg&title=Sample&description=This+is+a+test+description"
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(shareUrl));
startActivity(myIntent);
```